# Canceling the fixed After the input location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an input that I want to place in whatever area of the screen I click with the mouse every time anywhere else.

```
$("*").mouseup(function(e) {

    var x, y;

    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;

    $(".myInput").css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "z-index": "100",
        "margin-top": y,
        "margin-left": x
    });

});
```

By the above code the input really comes where I want but because it fixed position then it moves with the scroll of the screen.

I tried all the position option.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: share HTML please

Comment: try simple 'top' and 'left' property instead margins

Comment: I did it and it really places it where I want but it does not solve the problem that it then moves on the scroll screen. I want that after I place it it will stay in the same place.
thank you for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `absolute` instead of `fixed` which will stop it from sticking the page as you scroll.

> Use `window.scrollY` and add it to you `e.clientY` to make your `Y-Pos` relative to the scroll.

Also, use `top` & `left` instead of using `margin-top` & `margin-left`.

---

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  var x, y;

  x = e.clientX;
  y = e.clientY + window.scrollY;

  $(".myInput").css({
    "position": "absolute",
    "z-index": "100",
    "top": y,
    "left": x
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="myInput" />
<div></div>
```

Comment: Your solution is good but only to the top of the screen.
I want to place the input in the entire html page. This means that I'm scrolling down the screen and setting its position and I want it to stay there and not move.
thank you for the answer.

Comment: Do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: @YairBaruch working on it now. So you just want to position the input anywhere, including scrolled page?

Comment: True, and do not move later when I roll the page.

Comment: @YairBaruch fixed. Had to add `window.scrollY` to the `Y-Position`.

Comment: @YairBaruch always happy to help! :)